# JavaScript code not working when displaying value of html element

Tags: javascript

I want to display details in div element(id="displayStoragevol2"). Why below code is not working

```
<hr>
<h3>LocalStorage App Vol-2</h3>
<label>First Name: </label><input type="text" id="firstNamevol2">
<label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="lastNamevol2">
<button type="submit" id="fetchDetailsvol2">Submit</button>
<div id="displayStoragevol2"></div>
<hr>

    <script>
    /*LocalStorage Vol 2*/
    document.getElementById('fetchDetailsvol2').addEventListener('click', fetchFunction);
    var firstNamevol2 = document.getElementById('firstNamevol2').value;
    var lastNamevol2 = document.getElementById('lastNamevol2').value;
    var displayStoragevol2 = document.getElementById('displayStoragevol2');


    function fetchFunction(){               
        displayStoragevol2.innerHTML = firstNamevol2 + lastNamevol2;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Fetch value inside the function and use ` type="button"`

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read the values from the inputs when the page loads. At that time they are blank.

If you want to read the values when the element is clicked, you need to do so inside the event handler function.

Comment: I updated like this `function fetchFunction(){    
 displayStoragevol2.innerHTML = firstNamevol2.value; + lastNamevol2.value;
}` and it is not showing Last Name value

Comment: @AseemSharma — `firstNamevol2` and `displayStoragevol2` are copies of the `value` property when the page loads. They are empty strings, not input element objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your script section should be updated as follows,

```
<script>
document.getElementById('fetchDetailsvol2').addEventListener('click', fetchFunction);
var displayStoragevol2 = document.getElementById('displayStoragevol2');
function fetchFunction(){    
   var firstNamevol2 = document.getElementById('firstNamevol2').value;
   var lastNamevol2 = document.getElementById('lastNamevol2').value;
   displayStoragevol2.innerHTML = firstNamevol2 + lastNamevol2;
}
</script>
```

Since variable firstNamevol2 and lastNamevol2 were in global scope those variables are assigned the values when the page is loaded not when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care when you are declaring your variables in the process; they should be inside the click event handler.

Below is my working code (with variable and class names tidied).

HTML:

```
<h3>Input Data</h3>
<label>First Name:</label> <input type="text" id="firstName">
<label>Last Name:</label> <input type="text" id="lastName">
<button type="submit" id="fetchDetails">Fetch Details</button>
<hr>
<h3>Display Data:</h3>
<span id="displayFirstName"></span>
<span id="displayLastName"></span>
<hr>
```

Javascript:

```
function fetchData() {
  // On click of Fetch Details
  document.getElementById("fetchDetails").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Assign values to variables
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    // Display values in results field
    document.getElementById("displayFirstName").innerHTML = firstName;
    document.getElementById("displayLastName").innerHTML = lastName;
  });
}
fetchData();
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/darrenbarklie/pen/gWxQGJ)