# unable to fetch input from input field

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to get the input, entered by the user, from the input field; please help me out with this.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong here.

```js
var ftemp = document.getElementById("Farenheit").value;
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="number" id="Farenheit">
</td>
```

when entering value in input field in the web page, input value is not being fetched at all.

console.log-ing the variable just shows a blank line .

Comment: Please add the html code

Comment: Add complete code. You need to add the `eventListener` to your `input` to get entered value.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Probably you are just reading the value before you type anything into the field, and then never update `ftemp` again.

Comment: FYI in addition to everybody yelling to include more information @SujeetThakur you can use a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to embed an actual example in your question including a run button and all.

Comment: [Probably a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778334/javascript-code-not-working-when-displaying-value-of-html-element) and also [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840297/number-from-input-box-javascript/47840363) (but the question is missing a [mcve] so I can't be sure)

Comment: well the value is when you read it, it does not automatically update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript code not working when displaying value of html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778334/javascript-code-not-working-when-displaying-value-of-html-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code

```
var ftemp = document.getElementById("Farenheit").value;
```

gets you the *current* value of that `input` **at the time that line of code gets executed**.

***It does not update when the user changes the `input`s value.***

If you want it to do just that, you need to add an event listener to the `input` element that executes whenever the `input` **event** occurs:

```js
var ftemp;
document.getElementById("Farenheit").addEventListener('input', function() {
  ftemp = this.value;
  console.log(ftemp);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="Farenheit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the input element.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup',function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="Farenheit" >
```

Comment: This is *likely* a solution to the problem (although the keyup event wouldn't be my first choice), but the question lacks a [mcve] so it is hard to be sure, and if it is then some perfectly good duplicates have been highlighted in the comments already. This answer also lacks anything resembling an *explanation* for how this solves the problem.